# Protocol Buffers: get byte array from ByteString without copying

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Suppose I have a method `void foo(byte[] bytes)` requires a byte array as its parameter. Howerver, the Java type for byte arrays in Protobuf is `ByteString`.

I can use `byte[] toByteArray()` to get the byte array. But the problem is this method builds a new array using copy, which is relatively expensive. I would rather it return the underlying array directly, or return a view instead.

Is there any API for that, or the performance penalty is acceptable?

Comment: What does foo(byte[] bytes) method do? Can you change its implementation?

Comment: @kostya Do you mean I can use `ByteString#writeTo(OutputStream)` instead? But I really want my modules to be decoupled from each other.

Comment: Yes, something like `writeTo`. `OutputStream` is a class from the standard library, so you can still keep foo() method protobuf free. Javadocs for `ByteString` clearly say that what you ask is impossible: Like `String`, the contents of a `ByteString` can never be observed to change, not even in the presence of a data race or incorrect API usage in the client code.

Comment: Also unless you write something super optimized I wouldn't worry too much about overhead of array copying

Comment: @kostya "the contents of a ByteString can never be observed to change", and the only way to implement an unmodifiable array is to make a copy. So a getArray() api without copying is impossible. Right? Then I really miss C++'s pointer to const.

Comment: yes. There are no read-only arrays in Java, so the only way to protect from the API mis-use is to make a copy.

Answer (score 6):

In general that is impossible because there could be no such array inside some subclasses of `ByteString`. `BoundedByteString` can contain a bigger array, so copying is required to get an array of the right size. `RopeByteString` consists of other byte strings so copying is required to put it contents into one array. `LiteralByteString` stores it contents in an array of the right size, but it does not provide methods to access it directly.

But most probably `toByteArray()` will be fast enough for your needs as `System.arraycopy()` is very fast.

If you really have a performance problem because of long arrays copying and you don't want to pass `ByteString` directly, have a look at `asReadOnlyByteBuffer()` and `asReadOnlyByteBufferList()` methods. They wrap `ByteString` contents into `ByteBuffer` without copying them.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot get a `byte[]` from a `ByteString` without copying because this would allow you to modify the contents of the `ByteString`, which means that `ByteString` could no longer guarantee that it is immutable. This is much like why you cannot get a `char[]` from a `String` without copying, even though `String` is actually backed by `char[]` under the hood. This can be a security issue: when passing `String` or `ByteString` between security domains, it's important that the receiver can know that the sender is not modifying the string out from under them while they use it.

You can, however, call `asReadOnlyByteBufferList()` to get `ByteBuffer`s representing the underlying data without a copy, since `ByteBuffer` enforces immutability.

Answer (score 6):

See `com.google.protobuf.UnsafeByteOperations.unsafeWrap(byte[], int, int)`

Comment: The question is about turning a `ByteString` into `byte[]`, not about turning `byte[]` into `ByteString`.